# Razor cannot parse nested loops

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I go too many levels down the razor parser cannot handle my code. The following is what I am trying to achieve:

```
@if (Model.comments.Count > 0)
{       
    <ul class="media-list">

        @foreach (Comment comment in Model.comments)
        {
            <text>
            <li class="media">
                <a class="media-left">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" src="" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <p>@comment.content</p>

                    @foreach (Comment reply in comment.children)
                    {
                        <li class="media">
                            <a class="media-left">
                                <img data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" src="" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <p>@reply.content</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }

                </div>
            </li>
            </text>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

However it generates a series of errors about missing end tags (div and ul) which are present. If I take out the innermost foreach loop it works fine:

```
@foreach (Comment reply in comment.children)
```

Searching around I know that adding  tags can alleviate the problem but I cannot seem to get those to work either.

Edit: Thanks it was a combination of the two. I left text tags in from earlier testing and must have removed ul tags at some point too. Removing the text tags and adding ul tags solved it.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but have you tried closing your `<img>` tags?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. Yes I have at various stages. I have changed it now anyway.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted without explaining why it should be downvoted? I'm sick of those guys who do that for no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inner `foreach` loop surround the `<li>` elements in a `<ul>` tag

```
....
<ul> // add this
  @foreach (Comment reply in comment.children)
  {
    <li class="media">
      <a class="media-left">
        <img data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" src="" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <p>@reply.content</p>
      </div>
    </li>  
  }
</ul> // and this
```

Comment: Move the `ul` tag outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

your problem could be with `<text>` tag, that used in `Razor` to say that it isn't code. have you tried this:

```
@if (Model.comments.Count > 0)
{       
    <ul class="media-list">

        @foreach (Comment comment in Model.comments)
        {
            <text>
            <li class="media">
                <a class="media-left">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" src="" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
            </text>
                    <p>@comment.content</p>

                    @foreach (Comment reply in comment.children)
                    {
                        <li class="media">
                            <a class="media-left">
                                <img data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" src="" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <p>@reply.content</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
            <text>
                </div>
            </li>
            </text>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

But i think it's better to delete `<text>` tag from your cshtml.